# Alter a DRUPAL view so it adds a custom field ->textbox

Tags: drupal, view, textbox, addition, alter

I have a bit specific question.

I have a content type->TESTS
it has the more or less the normal fields.

There is a view that displays all of the tests. So far,so good.

But the requirement is to add a specific textbox-> SCORE of TEST for every instance.

And it should be different for all the logged in users.

For example. All users see the tests and can insert a result.
This result is recorded in the database.

What should be the best approach doing so ?

Maybe:
1.Create the field "ScoreOfTest"
2.Alter the view in a custom module

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the module you're looking for is [EditableFields](http://drupal.org/project/editablefields/). You don't say which Drupal version you're using, however there are recommended releases for D5, D6 and D7.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with splatio.  Another option is to use the webform module which is very easy to use and is designed for user input: http://drupal.org/project/webform/